# Flask demo application not working

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I wanted to try an Flask minimal application.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

It is working ok. If I add `app.debug = True` before `run()`, it does not work.

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 10, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 772, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 666, in run_simple
    os.set_inheritable(s.fileno(), True)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

I used Python 3.4.3, Flask 0.10.1, Werkzeug 0.11.1 and Windows 10. The behavior with or without virtualenv is the same.

Comment: I'm seeing this as well. It appears to be in the code that sets up the file reloader, but that's as far as I've gotten.

Comment: This worked on my computer (macbook pro). Can you try this in a virtual machine or different computer?

Comment: I try it on another PC with the same procedure and software version. The result is the same.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10. As far as I can tell, this occurs even when opening up a socket:
`s = socket.socket()
os.fstat(s.fileno())`

Comment: Same issue here on Windows 10. Tried running as admin, no fix. Running it with debug mode off works fine however.

Comment: If you need to turn on `Debug`. It should be `app.run(debug=True)`

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue on Windows 7 with Python 3.4.2. I ended up having to downgrade `Werkzeug` from version `0.11.1` to `0.10.4`. Full disclosure, I'm not a Python developer by trade since I write .NET in my day-to-day job and am lerning Python so I can't fully explain the reasoning here. Also, I just picked a version by going to [Pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=Werkzeug&submit=search) and serching "Werkzeug". If you were not aware, pypi.python.org is the source for your pip installs ;-).

To accomplish that I ended up uninstalling Werkzeug then re-installing it by specifying the version in `pip`. This worked for me in both my global environment as well as my "virtualenv" in my project.

```
pip uninstall Werkzeug
pip install Werkzeug==0.10.4
```

### EDIT

Here's the contents of my `requirements.txt` file. You can uninstall all the different packages you've already installed and install these specific versions by running the command `pip install -r requirements.txt`, assuming your working directory is where requirements.txt is located and your virtualenv is currently active. In Windows you can use relative paths if needed :-).

```
itsdangerous==0.24
Werkzeug==0.10.4
WTForms==2.0.2
SQLAlchemy==1.0.9
MarkupSafe==0.23
Jinja2==2.8
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1
Flask-WTF==0.10
```

Comment: Pinning my Werkzeug version to 0.10.4 worked!

Thanks very much. I'll see if I can identify the change that caused this.

Looks like this had already been fixed: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/issues/805